# In OS X Messages, can I disable double-click opening a conversation in its own window?

Tags: macos, touchpad, osx-mountain-lion, mouse-click

I keep Messages over on the left side of the screen so I can see when someoene's sent me a new message. But if I click to make the window active, and then click again to make a conversation active, it registers that as a double-click when I only want to switch to the conversation.

This causes it to open in its own window. This happens a majority of the times that I try to switch to a conversation, and it's pretty annoying. There's a menu item, a context menu item, and a keyboard shortcut for it when I really need it. So, is there a way to disable that double-click event altogether?